# MVC View Display

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I am using MVC c# with Razor 3

I have the following:

```
    <div> 

    </div>@Html.Label("First") &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp @Html.Label("Mi") &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp @Html.Label("Last") 



    </div>
```

I am using &nbsp to space between my labels. What is a more clean way of doing this.
I tried with SPAN with width but was not successful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use

```
 <table>
 <tr>
 <td width="33%">
@Html.Label("First")
</td>
 <td width="33%">
@Html.Label("Mi")
</td>
<td width="33%">
@Html.Label("Last") 
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

OR ...

```
<div style="width:300px;float:left;">
@Html.Label("First")
</div>
<div style="width:300px;float:left;">
@Html.Label("Mi")
</div>
<div style="width:300px;float:left;">
@Html.Label("Last") 
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have not found an answer by now let me suggest this razor nugget inline style

I use this style only for prototyping but it works great.

```
@Html.Label("State: ", null, new { style = " margin-left:10px; width: 35px; text-align: right; display: inline-block; font-size: 12px; " }) 
@Html.TextBox("state", @Model.BUSINESS_STATE, new { style = "width:20px;", maxlength = 2 })
@Html.Label("County: ", null, new { style = " margin-left:10px; width: 45px; text-align: right; display: inline-block; font-size: 12px; " }) 
@Html.TextBox("county", @Model.BUSINESS_CNTY, new { style = "width:20px;", maxlength = 2 })
```

Answer (score 0):

Combine the Variables and set the style sheet of that label to use word spacing

ex. word-spacing:30px;

You can add the css attribute as follows

```
@Html.Label("CompleteName", new {@class='WordSpacer'})

<style>
.WordSpacer {
    word-spacing:30px;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Stylesheets

You can use a css grid framework like blueprint css or you can add a margin right to the label:

```
<label style="margin-right: 50px">First</label><label>Last</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a tutorial on using CSS to display a form. http://woork.blogspot.com/2008/06/clean-and-pure-css-form-design.html